# How to convert blob to base64?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

```
         axios
            .get(RequestURL, { responseType: 'blob', withCredentials: false })
            .then((response) => {
                let imageNode = document.getElementById('image')
                let imgUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
                console.log(imgUrl)
                setImageServer(imgUrl)
            })

            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error)
            })
```

Html

```
<img id='image' src={ImageServer} alt='Girl in a jacket' /> //getting an actual image(its working)
```

above all code is working..but the problem is converting that blob into base64

Goal:- I am trying to convert this blob to base64 so I can save it in local storage

What I have tried:-

```
var image = document.getElementById('image')
                console.log(image.src)  // blob:http://localhost:3000/1c012729-b104-4fb5-a9a5-39aa782860b4
                var reader = new FileReader()
                reader.readAsDataURL(image.src)
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    var base64data = reader.result
                    console.log(base64data)
                }
```

By using this I am getting the error

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader':
> parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Yes, this is in react js, But It can easily be understood as normal js(only state is used)

Comment: I think this one can answer your question pretty well:
[How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what the function `setImageServer()` does, it's probably because `URL.createObjectURL()` returns a `DOMString` (which is basically a `string` type):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString

So your `console.log` is printing out a string representation of your blob object, not the blob itself. You could maybe try this to convert your `DOMString` to `base64`:

https://reference.codeproject.com/book/javascript/base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: setImageServer() is react state

Comment: gotcha, I see that now.  Hopefully this answer helps solve your problem!

Comment: Can you please add code for how to convert that dom string to base64?

Comment: its in the above link, under 'The "Unicode Problem"'

Comment: `var blob = b64EncodeUnicode(image.src)` and used into  `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)` and got the same error

Comment: I am also getting the output `YmxvYjpodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDAvMzZkNDkxNDYtN2RhYS00NGNjLWI3ZTEtYzZhZmY3YzE2N2Nj`  but passing this base64 to the `readAsDataURL ` throwing the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231979/discussion-between-sanket-kheni-and-phunkmasterp).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I am using `image.src` rather than using direct response from the server like `respone.data`

this is the solution.

```
  axios
                .get(RequestURL, { responseType: 'blob', withCredentials: false })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                    let imgData = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
                    setImageServer(imgData)
                    var reader = new FileReader()
    
                    reader.readAsDataURL(response.data)
                    reader.onloadend = function () {
                        var base64data = reader.result
                        console.log(base64data)
                    }
                })
```