# How to convert from Blob to Base64?

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

```
$.post("save-file.php",{text:txt},function(data){
                                        if (data.length>0) { 
                                            $("#out").html('');
                                            fetch(data)
                                                .then(resp => resp.blob())
                                                .then(blob => {
                                                    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                                                    a.style.display = 'none';
                                                    a.href = url;
                                                    // the filename you want
                                                    a.download = 'synonymizer-su-file-<?php echo date('YmdHis')?>.doc';
                                                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                                                    a.click();
                                                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                                                })
```

I tried to insert the function into the code somehow, but it didn't work out:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert blob to base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401649/how-to-convert-blob-to-base64)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.